# java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java

Buen día a todos,

tengo un problema para guardar una variable de un método de una clase a otra clase,

```
  public static void postOrquestadorIniciar() throws IOException { 
String parameters =  Util.getTemplate(Parameters.TEMPLATE_ORQUESTADOR_INICIAR);
    Util.UploadDocument(parameters);
    }
```

y me sale el error
java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.String

¿Qué debo hacer para que no me salga ese error ya que lo quiero guardar como un string y usarlo en otro metodo de otra clase?

Gracias de antemano a todos.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llamando a la función `postOrquestadorIniciar`?

Comment: Cómo está definida Util.getTemplate? Y por favor, añade una traza más completa del error

Comment: Prueba a cambiar void por String y dentro del metodo retornar el String.

Comment: Prueba si lo que indica Parameters.TEMPLATE_ORQUESTADOR_INICIAR realmente existe.